# If we have US7ASCII characterset why does it let us store non-ascii characters?

Tags: oracle, unicode, ascii

We have an Oracle database that has the `NLS_CHARACTERSET = US7ASCII`.

As a test, we ran an insert into a table that contains a `VARCHAR(4000)` field as were able to put a `CHR(176)` value in that column (`degrees symbol`).

That character doesn't appear to be supported by `US7ASCII`.

Why would the database allow that value to be stored in that column?

Comment: There must be something else going on because `US7ASCII` is a 7-bit encoding that doesn't support ['DEGREE SIGN' (U+00B0)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b0/index.htm) so you should be getting a literal `?` question mark on return (or maybe another replacement character). You can google for Globalization Support Guide, which explains this pretty well. Strange.

Comment: [Character Set Conversion in a Monolingual Scenario](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch2charset.htm#sthref165): "When a target character set does not contain all of the characters in the source data, replacement characters are used. If, for example, a server uses US7ASCII and a German client uses WE8ISO8859P1, then the German character `ß` is replaced with `?` and `ä` is replaced with `a`."

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36710360/difference-between-nls-nchar-characterset-abd-nls-characterset-for-oracle/36712457#36712457

Comment: When viewed through Oracle SQL developer, it appears as an upright rectangle character.
When viewed through Aqua Data studio, it appears as a degrees symbol.

Answer (score 2):

It works because following conditions are both true:

- Client character set is equal to your database character set.
- The character set permits any byte values

Your database character set and your client character set are set to `US7ASCII`. In such case each data is written/read one by one without any conversion, i.e. the bytes you send are exactly written to database. Probably you did not set `NLS_LANG` at all on your client side but Oracle defaults it to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII`.

`US7ASCII` is a 7-bit encoding. I assume a pure ASCII application (which could be fairly difficult to find) would just ignore the 8th bit which is stored in an 8-Bit architecture. Other character sets, e.g. `AL32UTF8` do not allow each byte value. In this case such characters will be replaced by a  placeholder, e.g. `¿` or `?`.

Note, you set your client character set to `US7ASCII` which is most likely not correct. Set it properly to the character set which is used by your application, then `°` will get replaced.

In case you use SQL*Plus check console codepage with command `chcp`, resp. `locale charmap`. Set your `NLS_LANG` environment variable accordingly before you start sqlplus.

Answer (score 0):

The database allows that value to be stored because Oracle will handle the character set conversion for you.

More info can be found here: [Special Characters in Oracle](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=special-characters-in-oracle)

Comment: That's right but, shouldn't he be getting `?` rather than `°`?

Comment: Doesn't that change depending on the character set of the operating system? I was under the belief that what gets displayed depends on the language/character set of the OS.

Comment: Perhaps that's the last fallback layer if you don't set the connection encoding anywhere (I don't know). But if the character cannot be physically stored on the server, there's no way for Oracle to figure out what character it was meant to be in the first place.