# How to pass correctly emojis from php web app into Oracle db

Tags: php, oracle, emoji

We have an php (codeigniter) web app that sending sms's. the db we connected to is oracle. when some customer trying to send emoji throgh our webapp the emoji is not displayed well on the mobile phone. we can see the emoji in sql plus but it not displeyed well on pl sql. we assuming it related to some encoding issue but can't point to the exact problem.

in addition when we receiving incoming messages from mobile phones and the message are not passted throght php the emojis displayed perfectly

this is how it looks when the message is incoming message

and this is how it looks when it comes from php נ˜€

we tryed to change the query in php to be like insert into sms(messaage) values(?)
we tried to change the type of the column from varchar2 to clob

Comment: I faced the same problem in the chat site I developed, I removed all emoji characters and replaced it with actual image links, e.g for  I replaced it with https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/11/svg/1f600.svg

Comment: Sheikh thanks but this solution not match to our case because we sending the message by sms to mobiles as text message so we cant transform the http url to emoji on the fly. it will displayed as url...

Comment: Lol never noticed the sms part, could be the encoding issue,  make sure your db has UTF-8 character set and refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52666272/oracle-cannot-store-emoji